# Can Smartphone see all network data and provide it to user at the same time like a cell signal meter? or it is limited to selected network?

Tags: android, flutter, signals, cell

I am trying to create a flutter app. My company wants me to design an app that can gather all nearby cellular towers data like RSRP, MNC, Band, RX, TX, etc.

I am using flutter plugin cell_info which only provide me the data of the tower which my cellphone is connected with. There are multiple apps available on app store but all are limited to the network with phone is connected.
Cell Signal meter can see all nearby towers data.

Can smartphone capable of getting all the towers data at the same time?
Smartphones can see the networks available all the time when we search it manually. does that mean it can also see RSRP, MNC..etc and provide it to user somehow?

if no, What makes cellphone different than cell signal meter?

if yes, how can I access all the data from android phone?

I tried looking through google but unable to find a good answer. Everyone saying it is not possible but what is the reason? hardware or software?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is try to set the network operator manually:
https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-manually-select-a-network-on-my-samsung-galaxy-device/

This might force the mobile device to connect to a diffrent base station

Your mobile device is of course able to detect and measure the signal power of different base stations and to quantify this. If there are several cells available, your device will choose regarding to the signal power.

How your mobile device connects to the LTE network is defined in the E-UTRA  protocal stack, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-UTRA.

The LTE cell selection process is described here: https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/BasicProcedure_LTE_Cell_Selection.html

**But**: I think it's a system design decision made that *choosing the best cell is only up to the device's firmware*. And for this reason the signal power data can' be found in any developer API.

This is in contrast to i.e. Bluetooth/WiFi, where:

The user can *choose* the network, even a wifi station with the worst available signal strength ==> the signal power data is *public* in an API.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Based on LTE cell selection. I can see Phone has to select the best from multiple operators but is there any way we can extract the data of all operators even after phone is set to one operator. For example. I am in Canada and I use Rogers. Can I get the RSRP for Bell, Virgin, Freedom.. etc. without me switching manually to different operators? Thanks